# image shadow in drag and drop on grid view?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android application in which if you drag image in gridview the images to clone moves with the finger to other position. How could I achieve this ? . I have seen codes from [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/), but was unable to understand how to convert it for grid view .

found one more tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEOpHg7ZMNk) But still could not figure out how to change it for grid view.....any suggestions or help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/