# Drag Drop TableLayout example?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, tablelayout

After looking all around the internet without finding out how to implement Drag Drop to devices not running 3.0 or newer. I am asking this question about a quite common question.

Is there an example/game-enigine/SDK/jar that makes you able to drag and drop Views into a TableLayout? And if somebody has done something earlier can they please share their code. I have already tried to modify GridView and ListView examples with no luck.

Please help me find out how I can do this to devices running earlier then 3.0.

Comment: I assume you will have to implement it yourself. So far as I know support library doesn't support that. Good reference on the way how to do it would be to take a look at the sources of Honeycomb or later, that support the mentioned feature.

From my experience from SWT, I would start by storing information about object on long click, then providing an image for dragging and listen to the position where the press was lifted. You have to have listeners for dragging(long click) and then dropping(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[karan421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171061/karan421) in [image shadow in drag and drop on grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998694/image-shadow-in-drag-and-drop-on-grid-view) introduced these links:
[drag and drop ui element](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEOpHg7ZMNk
And Ganesh also introduced this link
[improved drag drop for gridview](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/)
I hope above links help you.

Comment: The only one I have not tried yet is the mybringback. I am most likely going to set a bounty if that does not work.